# Shiny Docker Unable to Connect to API/Internet

Tags: r, docker, shiny, httr

I've setup a Shiny App using [docker shiny image](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/tidyverse/) and all works well until I attempt to call API using httr package.  From what I can get I'm unable to access internet from the App as I get the Timeout message from multiple sites, and verified the work from going through web browser.  Wondering what setting I need to change?

From the RStudio Console within the App:

```
> library(httr)
> r <- GET("http://httpbin.org/get")
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached: [httpbin.org] Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds
```

Here is my DockerFile:

```
FROM rocker/tidyverse

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev
RUN R -e 'install.packages("RPostgres")'
RUN R -e 'install.packages("DT")'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add the following libraries in Dockerfile and worked

```
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    curl \
    sudo \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev
```